# Gatling getting 'cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: method Cookie(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' Error

Tags: cookies, gatling

Currently getting error cannot find symbol

> [ERROR] symbol: method Cookie(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

for the following code. Could someone plz help

```java
public static ChainBuilder TestABC =
        exec(addCookie(Cookie("{Key}", "{Value}").withDomain("{DomainName}").withPath("/")))
        
                .exec(http("Test API")
                .get("{URL}"));
```

I tried to call `addCookie` method to set the cookies for the http request, as per the Gatling doc this should work
https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/helpers/#adding-a-cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is correct.

Either you're not using a modern version that supports Gatling Java (the latest to date is 3.9.5), or your imports are a mess (missing imports, mixing conflicting imports for Gatling Java and Gatling Scala).

Please check the documentation for what your imports should look like: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/simulation/#dsl-imports

Comment: Updating DSL imports worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help